# Is type specifier required for const?

Tags: c++, constants

Is a type specifier required here?

```
const c = 7;
```

Bjarne Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming Language' on page 80 says that this is illegal. However, I've been practicing some [brainbench](http://www.brainbench.com/) tests, and one of the questions states that the type defaults to int. Brainbench is usually correct, so I'm unsure of which reference is right, and I've been unable to find anything in the standard. Does anyone have a definitive answer and a reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default type of int is valid for C, but not for C++. Even in C this style of coding should be avoided. Also note that Bjarne Stroustrup's book is one of the most authoritative reference for standard C++.

Comment: The most authoritative short of the standard itself of course.

Comment: @MSalters Agreed. Modified the post to reflect this.

Comment: It seems a shame that this isn't legal code given that the C++0x (draft) standard is moving towards type inference:


    auto x = 7;  // x is inferred to be an int from typeof(7)


More info on Bjarne's FAQ: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#auto

Comment: Far from a shame: with auto, you show that you intend to let the compliler decide the type. Here, you might just have forgotten.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ I would believe Stroustrup over any place but a standard.

Perhaps the question was about C not C++?

The [draft C++0x standard](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/SC22-N-4411.pdf) in section 7.1.6 says

> At least one type-speciﬁer that is not a cv-qualiﬁer is required in a declaration unless it declares a constructor, 
>   destructor or conversion function.83 A type-speciﬁer-seq shall not deﬁne a class or enumeration unless it 
>   appears in the type-id of an alias-declaration (7.1.3).

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the standard... but just looking at a statement like `const c = 7;` screams bad code style to me. As far as compiler compatibility... it's probably going to be hit-and-miss. Microsoft Visual Studio's compiler won't have any part of it when compiling a C++ file (.cpp extension) but doesn't choke on it when compiling a C file (.c extension) mainly because the C standard allows for defaulting variables as `int` when no type is specified.

Comment: Unfortunately these types of tests ask extremely esoteric things, facts that you would never rely upon if you were writing code (if you understand it, it's almost certain the next person wont!)